# Developing modular C++ program with communication between plugins

Tags: c++, design-patterns, plugins, modular-design

I'm trying to figure out some C++ programing and OO concepts.

What I want is i want to have a core exe which scans a folder for dll's then loads it's start function and launches the plugin. This has already been developed and is running fine.

I'm in a position right now I've never been before and I'm new to C++ and winapi programming.

What I want to do is just drop a dll in the plugin folder, and the core add's the functionality.

This is working right now, but the plugins are running like separated exe's. Now I want to communicate between plugins if they are available.

I tried setting up the dll as a object factory, but then I'm here with this object inside of my code expecting the dll to be there.

Does anybody know any good design patterns I could use without just trial and error, and some reinvention of the wheel? Google isn't showing me what I search for and I'm too new to this to know any good knowledgebases.

Comment: You seem to mix several unrelated issues together, and it is not clear what your actual problem is. Show some code, or perhaps pseudocode.

Comment: Agree with n.m.: Your question needs to be more specific. What sort of communication? How do the modules know about each other?